# Deploy docker image with TFS to AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, tfs, tfsbuild, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm building docker images with TFS. After the image is build I would like to push it to Amazon EC2 Container Registry (ECR).

What is the best way to achieve this?

There is a [extension for TFS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools) to e.g. upload data to AWS S3 or run AWS CLI commands. With the CLI I could run `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region xxx` and then push the image manually. As our buildserver is a linux machine and "AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Script" runs only on Windows it also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TFS extension mentioned](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools) in the question supports now pushing images to ECR. (Version 1.0.14)

There is now the "AWS Elastic Container Registry Push" task
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the extension and just figure out how to get TFS to trigger shell scripts upon successful build. (I don't know exactly how to do that half of the equation, but I do know how to do the rest).

You can download the [AWS CLI for Unix](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which gives you this command. Then `docker login $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region xxx)` as you've seen and `docker push` your image to the ECR you've created.

The best practice I've seen is to keep the little "build scripts" like this in the same repository as your code, in like a `build-scripts` folder or something. Then the "hard part" is only hooking up TFS to run that script on success, and that's all that needs to know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Running a script with TFS is not a problem. The part I don't like here is that I would need to hard code the password for AWS in the script. This is bad as anyone can see it and if i need to change it I would need to change it in each project.
Never the less it's a way to go but for me only a option if there is no other way.

Comment: The AWS CLI lets you place the credentials information in three(or more?) different places. The ones I can think of off the top of my head are text file in ~/.aws , environmental variables the AWS CLI looks for, or yes I think parameters to the cli app. The file approach would give you a common place to put creds so you can use them for many projects.